# Magento 2: UpgradeData duplicates static blocks when I try to update them

Tags: magento2.2.3, upgrade-script, upgradeschema

My code looks like this:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory
 */
private $_blockFactory;

...

$this->_blockFactory
        ->setStoreId(0)
        ->load('some-identifier', 'identifier')
        ->setData([
            'title' => 'Some Title',
            'identifier' => 'some-identifier',
            'is_active' => 1,
            'stores' => [0],
            'content' => 'Some Content...',
        ])->save();
```

Everytime I run this code, it creates a new static block with the same identifier.

---

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use factory for existing blocks. You should use the repository:
\Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require './app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$searchCriteriaBuilder = $obj->create('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder');
/** @var \Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository */
$blockRepository = $obj->create('Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface');
$searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(
    'identifier',
    'home-page-block',
    'eq'
)->create();
/** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $item */
$items = $blockRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
reset($items);
$item = $items[key($items)];
echo $item->getTitle();
$item->setTitle($item->getTitle() . '_1');
$blockRepository->save($item);
echo $item->getTitle();
```

This works for me

UPDATE
In case if you need ***"insert or update if exists"*** use this code:

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require './app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

/** @var \Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository */
$blockRepository = $obj->create(Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface::class);
/** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory */
$blockFactory = $obj->create(Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory::class);
$searchCriteriaBuilder = $obj->create(Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder::class);

$searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(
    'identifier',
    'home-page-block',
    'eq'
)->create();
/** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $item */
$items = $blockRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
if (count($items)) {
    reset($items);
    $block = $items[key($items)];
} else {
    $block = $blockFactory->create();
}
$block->setTitle($item->getTitle() . '_1');
$blockRepository->save($item);
```

Comment: Will it also work if the block doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Of course not, you asked about update code.

Comment: I updated my answer for you. Now it inserts new if not exists, and update if exists

Comment: You are welcome. Please let me know if it's not fit for you target.

Comment: @Pini how is it going along?

Comment: That didn't work for me. I tried to insert/update the same block on different stores & got the error: "A block identifier with the same properties already exists in the selected store."

Comment: Actually, it did create the blocks for each store on the first run. But on the second, when I tried to change the content I got the error on setup:upgrade.

Comment: Please share your code. And error that you got

Comment: Error: "A block identifier with the same properties already exists in the selected store."

Comment: Code: Same thing you did + I duplicated the set/save part & changed stores & data.